# Cannot find Queryover in Hibernate 4.x (java, eclipse)

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a join by using the Queryover construction:
This is the creation of the sessionfactory:

```
      private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  try {
   // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  }
```

Creation of session:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

In the session i expect the .QueryOver, but i cannot find it,
find a lot of information for C# but not for java,
can someone help me? Thx

Comment: NHibernate is for .Net on only. For Java, another project is called Hibernate, without the prefixed 'n'.

Comment: To put it another way: Try googling for Hibernate instead of NHibernate and you should find more java-related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

QueryOver is only for .NET, working with java you need to use [Hibernate Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Here is one example:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person where name = :n ");
query.setParameter("na", "John");
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: Ok, thx, is there in java an alternative for the queryover, because i want to query in a generic way, i mean not placing text in the create join for example but using properties just like in the queryover construction in .NET. I like the strong typing. Is this possible in java? Thx

Comment: I never heard about anything similar to this in Java... try some google about it